# Get multiple strings between two matched characters using jquery regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

"I expect five hundred dollars `<Sample500>`. and new brackets `<600>` next `< Sample>`".

in the above sentence i want to get the strings between "<" and ">" like `["Sample500","600"," Sample"]`

for that i'm using the regular expression like  -->

```
"I expect five hundred dollars <Sample500>. and new brackets <600> next <Sample>".match(/\<<[^>]+>\>/g)
```

please provide valid regular expression

Answer (score 3):

this will do the trick for you:

```
var s = "I expect five hundred dollars <Sample500>. and new brackets <600> next <Sample>";
var matches = [];
s.replace(/<(.*?)>/g, function(g0,g1){
  matches.push(g1);
});
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<([^>]*)>
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/1